# Generating all ordered samples with replacement

Tags: matlab, sampling

I would like  to generate an array which contains all ordered samples of length k taken from a set of n elements `{a_1,...,a_n}`,  that is all the k-tuples `(x_1,...,x_k)`  where each `x_j` can be any of the `a_i` (repetition of elements is allowed), and whose total number is `n^k`.

Is there a built-in function in Matlab to obtain it?

I have tried to write a code that iteratively uses the `datasample` function, but I couldn't get what desired so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative way to get all the tuples is based on k-base integer representation.

If you take the k-base representation of all integers from 0 to `n^k - 1`, it gives you all possible set of k indexes, knowing that these indexes start at 0.

Now, implementing this idea is quite straightforward. You can use `dec2base` if `k` is lower than 10:

```
X = A(dec2base(0:(n^k-1), k)-'0'+1));
```

For `k` between 10 and 36, you can still use `dec2base` but you must take care of letters as there is a gap in ordinal codes between '9' and 'A':

```
X = A(dec2base(0:(n^k-1), k)-'0'+1));
X(X>=17) = X(X>=17)-7;
```

Above 36, you must use a custom made code for retrieving the representation of the integer, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683672/1507014). But IMO you may not need this as 2^36 is quite huge.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [`ndgrid`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html): it generates the grid elements in any dimension.

In the case `k` is fixed at the moment of coding, get all indexes of all elements `a` this way:

```
[X_1, ..., X_k] = ndgrid(1:n);
```

Then build the matrix `X` from vector `A`:

```
X = [A(X_1(:)), ..., A(X_k(:))];
```

If `k` is a parameter, my advice would be to look at the code of `ndgrid` and adapt it in a new function so that the output is a matrix of values instead of storing them in `varargout`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. In my case k is a parameter of the code, so maybe your second answer is more appropriate.

Comment: @hardhu Both produce the same index array, it's up to you to choose the one you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

What about this solution, I don't know if it's as fast as yours, but do you think is correct?

```
function Y = ordsampwithrep(X,K)
%ordsampwithrep Ordered samples with replacement
%   Generates an array Y containing in its rows all ordered samples with  
%   replacement of length K with elements of vector X
X = X(:);
nX = length(X);
Y = zeros(nX^K,K);
Y(1,:) = datasample(X,K)';
k = 2;
while k < nX^K +1
    temprow = datasample(X,K)';
    %checknew = find (temprow == Y(1:k-1,:));
    if not(ismember(temprow,Y(1:k-1,:),'rows'))
        Y(k,:) = temprow;
        k = k+1;
    end
end
end
```